# Item gets duplicated in adapter, when we delete or update item from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Items in adapter gets duplicated 2 or 3 times when we try to delete item from list in firebase realtime database.

Last item in adapter didnt gets removed after we perform deletion in firebase database realtime.

Tried notifyDataSetChanged().

```
override fun onItemClicked(
    adapterPosition: Int,
    mUserListProfile: ArrayList<UserProfile>
) {
     mShortlistedProfileVM?.deleteUserProfile(mUserListProfile.get(adapterPosition))
            mShortlistProfileAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

}
```

Last item in adapter should be removed, after we perform deletion [operation in firebase realtime database. and Duplicated item should be removed.

Comment: Share the code of your listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Solution work for me :

This code will remove last item in adapter after performing deletion operation in firebase realtime database.

mAcceptedList.removeAt(adapterPosition);
  mShortlistProfileAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

```
override fun onItemClicked(
    adapterPosition: Int,
    mUserListProfile: ArrayList<UserProfile>
) {
           mShortlistedProfileVM?.deleteUserProfile(mUserListProfile.get(adapterPosition))
            mAcceptedList.removeAt(adapterPosition);
            mShortlistProfileAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
}
```

2. To Prevent item gets duplicated.

Clear your list before adding data into list.

```
mAcceptedList.clear()    <---add this line of code. 

val listSize = etrieveDataResponse.userViewedProfile!!.mViewedProfileList.size
 val mListUserProfile = retrieveDataResponse.mViewedProfileList
 for (i in 0..listSize - 1) {
  if (mListUserProfile.get(i).mProfileStatus == true) {
  mAcceptedList.add(mListUserProfile.get(i))
 }
```

}
  showDataOnAdapter(mAcceptedList)

Answer (score 0):

1) You can try swap i.e

```
public class TestApdater extends RecyclerView.Adapter<....> {    
...
private static List<Mobel> mData;
...    
public void swap(List list){
        if (mData != null) {
            mData.clear();
            mData.addAll(list);
        }
        else {
            mData = list;
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

2) Or if this also doesn't work you can simple add this on your on click for your delete button , please note its not the best solution but works .

```
    Intent i=new Intent(this, SameActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|
FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```